# What does this regex pattern describe: ".{5,}+"

Tags: regex

One of the HTML input fields in an app I'm working on is being validated with the following regex pattern:

```
.{5,}+
```

What is this checking for?

Other fields are being checked with this pattern which I also don't understand:

```
.+
```

Answer (score 18, accepted):

We can break your pattern down into three parts:

The [dot](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html) is a wildcard, it matches any character (except for newlines, by default, unless the `/s` [modifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/modifiers.html) is set).

`{5,}` is specifies [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html) on the dot. It says that the dot must match at least 5 times. If there was a number after the comma, the dot would have to match between 5 and that number of times, but since there's no number, it can match infinite times.

In your first pattern, the `+` is a [possessive quantifier](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html) (see below for how `+` can mean different things in different situations). It tells the regular expression engine that once it's satisfied the previous condition (ie. `.{5,}`), it should not try to backtrack.

---

Your second pattern is simpler. The dot still means the same thing as above (works as a wildcard). However, here the `+` has a different meaning, and is a repetition operator, meaning that the dot must match 1 or more times (that could also be expressed as `.{1,}`, as we saw above).

As you can see, `+` has a different meaning depending on context. When used on its own, it is a repetition operator. However when it follows a different repetition operator (either `*`, `?`, `+` or `{...}`) it becomes a possessive quantifier.

Comment: +1 for the clearest explanation of regualar expressions i've seen to date.

Answer (score 4):

The `+` means after another quantifier (`{5,}`) means a [possessive match](http://www.regular-expressions.info/possessive.html), i.e. once a match is found, *do not backtrack**.

For instance, the pattern `.{5,}x` will match `abcdex`:

1. `.{5,}` matches `abcdex`.
2. `x` matches nothing.
3. So backtrack `.{5,}` and let it match `abcde`.
4. Now `x` matches that last `x`.

But `.{5,}+x` will *not* match `abcdex`:

1. `.{5,}+` matches `abcdex`.
2. `x` matches nothing.
3. Cannot backtrack the `.{5,}+`. We have to stop here.

<sub>*: Even the pattern cannot be backtracked, the matched strings can still be deleted as a whole. For instance, `a?.{5,}x` will match {`a?` → `a`, `.{5,}+` → `bcdex`, `x` → no match}, and then delete the whole `.{5,}+` and `a` and restart with {`a?` → , `.{5,}+` → `abcdex`, `x` → no match}. Therefore, we can also say that the `+` makes the quantifier "atomic".</sub>

---

On the other hand, `+` alone just mean `{1,}`, i.e. match one or more times.

Answer (score 3):

Any character, 5 or more times.

- "." means any character except a line break.
- {m, n} defines a bounded interval. "m" is the min. "n" is the max. If n is not defined, as is here, it is unlimited.
- "+" means possessive.

Comment: `+` is not greedy. Regular expressions are greedy by default. You're likely thinking of `?`, which makes a pattern **lazy**. `+` is possessive.

Answer (score 3):

`.{5,}+` means

1. [Match any single character that is not a line break character](http://www.regular-expressions.info/dot.html)

   1. [Between 5 and unlimited times; as many times as possible, without giving back (possessive)](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)

`.+` is the same thing but it matches between 1 and unlimited times, giving back as needed (greedy).

As I've mentioned many times before, I'm a huge fan of [RegexBuddy](http://www.regexbuddy.com/).  It's "Create" mode is excellent for deconstruction regular expressions.